# Do Karate support .avro file as an input request?

Tags: karate

We have a requirement where we need to send .avro file as an input request to our API's. Really stuck at this point. If any detail example provided would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Java interop: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

You need to write a helper (start with a static method) to convert JSON to Avro and vice versa. I know teams using this for gRPC. Read this thread for tips: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/412

Also there is even a "karate-grpc" project: https://github.com/pecker-io/karate-grpc

Also see:

https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1128170638223364097

https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1417023536082812935

Comment: Thanks a lot peter, i knew this is out of karate asking for avro to json and vice-versa conversion reference. Any help on to this?

Comment: @SandeepPadala I googled and found a few links. try it !