# Karate DSL : Support for MQTT testing

Tags: automation, karate

Karate supports web-socket and i was able to test websockets. But when i try to test MQTT, the connection params were not accepted and it looks like MQTT is not supported at all. Can anyone be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Find a Java library for MQTT and you will be up and running. Please refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#consumer-provider-example

also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62826394/143475