# How to integrate gRPC with karate

Tags: grpc, karate

I am trying to test gRPC with Karate. My requirement is to import the .proto file and utilize the services. I have tried some of the karate-grpc examples, but got the below error:

`Could not resolve dependencies for project com.github.thinkerou:karate-grpc-helper:jar:1.0.3: Failed to collect dependencies at com.github.thinkerou:karate-grpc-core:jar:1.0.3:`

Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps that project is not maintained anymore. I suggest you look at this thread, the concept is very simple and what we recommend - just write one java adapter, and it is a one-time work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62826394/143475 - you can see how someone has created a kafka adapter the same way: https://github.com/Sdaas/karate-kafka