# How to configure a .pem certificate in Karate feature file

Tags: karate

I am trying to automate a gRPC service call using Karate-Grpc client as illustrated in https://github.com/pecker-io/karate-grpc. Our service call uses a .pem certificate. How to configure this certificate in .feature file? I have gone through some of the examples which are using the below syntax.Do i need to convert the .pem to .jks?

Background:
* configure ssl = { keyStore: 'util/certificate/abc.xyz.net.jks', keyStorePassword: 'keystorepassword'}

Regards
Debayan

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `karate-grpc` but I think it is highly unlikely that it integrates with the `configure ssl` part of Karate - which is designed for the HTTP client.

Personally I recommend you writing a gRPC client by hand (one-time effort) including any SSL config or equivalent (which you should have working somewhere in your project already). See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62826394/143475